# Javascript Not deleting all cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am using following code to delete a cookie:

```
document.cookie = "CookieName=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
```

There are two cookies, one in on domain `www.websiteaddress.com` and other is on `.websiteaddress.com`.
When I am on page `www.websiteaddress.com` the cookie having domain address `www.websiteaddress.com` gets deleted but other one is not deleted. How can I delete both cookies while loading javascript on `www.websiteaddress.com`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not **allowed** to delete cookies on another site. Because there is no guarantee that you own both `www.websiteaddress.com` and `.websiteaddress.com`. You can only delete cookies that you set for the current domain.

Comment: Both cookies are on same domain but the address used to save them is different. One is with www and other one is without www.

Comment: you won't be alllowed to delete the cookies of .websiteaddress.com from www.websiteaddress.com.